# Keep playing audio while clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to code Simons game with Html and Javascript/Jquery. My question is about the sound. It is supposed to continue with no interval while clicking on a button. But so far I have this beep, beep, beep sound while clicking. It should sound like beeeeeeeeep. That is, no silence between sound while the track ends and restarts. This is what I have so far:

```
var timeout;

$("#green").mousedown(function() {
  timeout = setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementById('audio1').play();
 },100)
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
  clearInterval(timeout);
  return false;
});
```

And the relevant Html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="colorDiv" id="green"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv" id="red"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="colorDiv" id="blue"></div>
</div>

<audio id="audio1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: You should have to use 2 audio elements, one should start at the end of first one

Comment: Could you explain a little more, please?

Comment: Use 2 audio element, one cloned from another. Get the duration of the audio. Play first one and within at the end of  the duration of audio play second. It's only way to avoid delay.